# How to install Backtrack along Ubuntu?

Tags: backtrack

During my Ubuntu installation I have let Ubuntu to use all the hard-disk. But now I want to install Backtrack alongside my Ubuntu. How do I proceed?

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu. You should consult their manual at http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/backtrack-hard-drive-install/

Comment: Yes, shrinking the partition to manage space is for ubuntu.

Comment: ^You could do that with nearly any distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Backtrack doesn't allow you to partition your HDD during installation, you can use an Ubuntu live USB, which includes Gparted, to partition it first.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make a partition and then install backtrack

So basically dual boot it

Answer (score -1):

If your entire hard disk has ubuntu on it, use gparted or a partition tool of your choice to create empty space, following which you can use that space to install backtrack, following the guide that runs along while the installation takes place.